# ReactJS + Fluxxor cascading actions causes error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, flux

I've got a parent component that has 2 child components;

**UPDATE**
I've rewritten some statements and code to make it more understandable.

Parent: `ReservationFormComponent`
Children: `ReservationTypePanel` & `ReservationCalendarPanel`

The parent component `ReservationFormComponent` initially displays the `ReservationTypePanel` only. The other sibling `ReservationCalendarPanel` is hidden until an item is selected on `ReservationTypePanel`.

So the problem is when an item is selected in `ReservationTypePanel` the `ReservationCalendarPanel` is rendered with initial values set in the `ReservationFormStore` store. Particularly

```
    initialize: function(){
      this.reservationType = void 8;
      this.pickupTime = moment().add('minutes',30);
    }
```

So when the `ReservationCalendarPanel` is rendered, its child Component `DateTimeField` which accepts the state `pickupTime` get re-rendered and fires up the `onChange` event which calls for another action

```
    return DateTimeField({
      pickupTime: pickupTime,
      onChange: function(time){
        // Here is where the action gets called again
        this$.getFlux().actions.setReservationPickupTime(time);
      }
    });
```

And greets me with this error `Uncaught Error: Cannot dispatch an action while another action is being dispatched`

I've tried my best to trim down the codes below. I wasn't using `JSX` because the original code was in `LiveScript` so I just took the compiled code to display here instead.

This is the parent component `ReservationFormComponent`

```
ReservationFormComponent = React.createClass({
    get flux(){ // Instantiating Fluxxor
      return new Fluxxor.Flux({ // These are the stores
        'reservation-form': new ReservationFormStore,
        'reservation-types': new ReservationTypeStore
      }, { // These are the actions
        setReservationType: function(value){
          return this.dispatch('SET_RESERVATION_TYPE', value);
        },
        setReservationPickupTime: function(value){
          return this.dispatch('SET_RESERVATION_PICKUP_TIME', value);
        }
      });
    },
    componentWillMount: function(){
        this.flux.store('reservation-form').addListener('change', this.onChange);
    },
    onChange: function(){ // This triggers the re-render to display the ReservationCalendarPanel
        this.setState({
            pickupTime: this.flux.store('reservation-form').pickupTime
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        reservationType = this.state.reservationType;
        return form({
                className: 'container'
            }, ReservationTypePanel({
                flux: this.flux
            }), reservationType ? ReservationCalendarPanel({
                flux: this.flux
            }) : null // This conditional to mount or not mount the component
        );
    }

});
```

The `ReservationTypePanel` Component. Here, the rendered component listens to `onClick` event and dispatches `setReservationType` action.

```
ReservationTypePanel = React.createClass({
  mixins: [fluxxor.FluxMixin(react)],
  onSelectReservationType: function(reservationType){
    var this$ = this;
    return function(event){
      this$.getFlux().actions.setReservationType(reservationType);
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    var this$ = this;
    return ReservationTypeItem({
      onClick: this$.onSelectReservationType(type);
    })
  }
});
```

The `ReservationCalendarPanel` Component. Here is where the DateTimeField is rendered and receives the state from the `ReservationFormStore` and sets the value which causes another dispatch. This is where the error comes.

```
ReservationCalendarPanel = React.createClass({
  mixins: [fluxxor.FluxMixin(react)],
  getInitialState: function() {
      return {pickupTime: moment()} // sets the current time
  },
  componentWillMount: function(){
    this.getFlux().store('reservation-form').addListener('change-pickup-time', this.onFlux);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this.getFlux().store('reservation-form').removeListener('change-pickup-time', this.onFlux);
  },
  render: function() {
    var this$ = this;

    if (this.state.pickupTime) {
      pickupTime = moment(this.state.pickupTime);
    }

    return DateTimeField({
      date: pickupTime,
      onChange: function(time){
        // Here is where the action gets called again
        this$.getFlux().actions.setReservationPickupTime(time);
      }
    });
});
```

This is the `DateTimeField` this is where the

```
DateTimeField = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      text: ''
    };
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
    this.setDate(nextProps.date);
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
    $(this.getDOMNode()).datepicker()
      .on('changeDate', this.onChangeDate)
      .on('clearDate', this.onChangeDate);
    this.setDate(this.props.date);
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function(){
    return $(this.getDOMNode()).datepicker('remove');
  },
  getDatepickerDate: function(){
    return $(this.getDOMNode()).datepicker('getDate');
  },
  setDate: function(date){
    if (!this.isMounted()) {
      return;
    }
    if (moment(date).isSame(this.getDatepickerDate, 'day')) {
      // If there is no change between the date that
      // is about to be set then just ignore and
      // keep the old one.
      return;
    }
    date = date ? moment(date).toDate() : void 8;
    $(this.getDOMNode()).datepicker('setDate', date);
  },
  onChangeDate: function(event){
    if (this.props.onChange) {
      this.props.onChange(event.date);
    }
  },
  render: function(){
    return this.transferPropsTo(input({
      type: 'text',
      className: 'form-control'
    }));
  }
});
```

If in case here is the store:

```
ReservationFormStore = fluxxor.createStore({
    actions: {
      SET_RESERVATION_TYPE: 'setReservationType',
      SET_RESERVATION_PICKUP_TIME: 'setPickupTime'
    },
    initialize: function(){
      this.reservationType = void 8;
      this.pickupTime = moment().add('minutes',30);
    },
    setReservationType: function(reservationType){
      this.reservationType = reservationType;
      this.reservationTypeValidate = true;
      this.emit('change-reservation-type', this.reservationType);
      this.emit('change');
    }
    setPickupTime: function(pickupTime){
      this.pickupTime = pickupTime;
      this.pickupTimeValidate = true;
      this.emit('change-pickup-time', this.pickupTime);
      this.emit('change');
    }
});
```

Comment: It looks like each action dispatch happens within an `onChange` handler, so they shouldn't cascade unless `DateTimeField` is calling `onChange` as soon as it renders. If that's the case, `pickupTime` should be initialized in the store and received in `ReservationCalendarPanel` somehow to be passed to `DateTimeField`. If I'm off base, please add the code for `DateTimeField`.

Comment: You might also see if using [batched updates as described here](http://fluxxor.com/guides/react.html#batched-updates) helps.

Comment: @BinaryMuse thank you for your response. It seems that the `DateTimeField` triggers the `onChange` event as soon as it renders. I'll add the code. Also I've rewritten the problem and refactored the code to make it more understandable. Notice that the `ReservationCalendarPanel` is not mounted initially, it only gets mounted when an item in `ReservationTypePanel` is selected. I've seen that batched updates you referred but I'm trying to figure out what is causing this issue and how to resolve it. I'm currently running `0.10` version of `React` so I can't take advantage of that batchUpdate atm.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand the flow of your code, but I noticed one thing that could be improved and may help: inside the `setDate()` function you actually change your input `date` variable, with the statement `date = date ? moment...`. Better: create a new `var tempDate` variable and pass that to your datepicker. Because `setDate()` is also invoked with `this.props.date` and you should not change props.